# Angular2 variable not updating after change

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to build a component where the user inputs an image which is then uploaded to s3 and then the url for that image is displayed.  I have the following html template

```
{{imgUrls}}
<div>
      <input type="file" (change)="testOnChange($event)"/>
</div>
```

which is connected to a component containing the following typescript code

```
    public imgUrls = [];

    testOnChange(event){
        var files = event.srcElement.files;
        this.getSignedRequest(files[0]);
    }

    uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
        console.log("inside uploadFile()");

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
                if(xhr.status === 200){
                    this.imgUrls.push(url);
                    console.log(this.imgUrls);
                }
                else{
                    alert('Could not upload file.');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(file);
    }

    getSignedRequest(file){
        console.log("inside getSignedRequest()");
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', `http://localhost:3000/job/sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}`);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
                if(xhr.status === 200){
                    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    this.uploadFile(file, response.signedRequest, response.url);
                }
                else{
                    alert('Could not get signed URL.');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

The logging statement inside `uploadFile()` does actually show the updated `imgUrls` variable containing the correct url - however the `{{imgUrls}}` never actually changes in the html template.  I'm not sure why the logging statement shows that `imgUrls` has changed but the change is never reflected in the actual html template.  Am I somehow binding the variable incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you using primitive  `XMLHttpRequest` which is not observable and not using angular http?

Comment: I was following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node - but I suppose that is the reason, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a wrapper for XmlHttpRequest called BrowserXhr and you should use Http service in angular. I.e:

```
constructor(private _http: Http){  
    _http.get(url); // etc
}
```